# GlobalPicklist no longer a valid MetaData type in 38.0?

Tags: apex, metadata, migration-tool, package.xml

Trying to migrate a global picklist using a 37.0 package.xml, but if I change the version to 38.0, I get an error that GlobalPicklist is not supported in API version 38.0.

Anyone notice it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, [GlobalPicklist](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_globalpicklist.htm) has been replaced by [GlobalValueSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_globalvalueset.htm). This is outlined in the relevant documentation and was mentioned in the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_picklists_new_api.htm).

> ## Streamlined Metadata API for Picklists
>
> We bring you elegance and efficiency with a reimagined Metadata API for picklists, with no wasted elements to clutter your API calls. The new structure clearly differentiates between global picklist value sets, local custom picklists, and standard picklists, making it super-easy to track your fields and values. This feature is available in both Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic.
>
> If you're using API v37.0, you can still use the existing elements for defining picklists and their values. If you're using API v38.0, your brain is about to get a break because defining all types of picklists makes more sense.
>
> Here's a high-level comparison:
>
> ```
> +------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
> | Metadata Type in API Version 37.0  | Metadata Type in API Version 38.0 |
> +------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
> | Picklist                           | StandardValueSet, ValueSet        |
> +------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
> | GlobalPicklist                     | GlobalValueSet                    |
> +------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
> | GlobalPicklistValue, PicklistValue | CustomValue                       |
> +------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
> | GlobalPicklistTranslation          | StandardValueSetTranslation,      |
> |                                    | GlobalValueSetTranslation         |
> +------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
> ```
>
> For type and field descriptions and sample definitions, see the Metadata API Developer Guide.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Hmm. I need to read the release notes more often. They've gotten far more amusing than they were previously.

Comment: They're definitely worth a read these days. Seems there are a few worthy nuggets each release.